# My dashbord - error

Tags: dashboard

Using Civicrm 4.6.5 on joomla 6.6, 
when selecting "My `Dashboard on the left panel this error appear 
backTrace

```
#0 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#4 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#5 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(899): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column '0LEFT' in 'on clause'")
#7 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#9 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#10 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#11 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#12 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1221): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...", TRUE)
#13 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4624): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#14 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Selector/Search.php(216): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->searchQuery(0, 0, NULL, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NULL)
#15 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(233): CRM_Activity_Selector_Search->getTotalCount(4, NULL)
#16 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Form/Search.php(283): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->__construct(Object(CRM_Activity_Selector_Search), NULL, NULL, 4, Object(CRM_Activity_Form_Search), 1, "activity_")
#17 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Form/Search.php(119): CRM_Activity_Form_Search->postProcess()
#18 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Activity_Form_Search->preProcess()
#19 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#20 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Activity_Form_Search), "display")
#21 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Activity_Form_Search), "display")
#22 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#23 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Page/UserDashboard.php(62): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#24 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Page/UserDashboard.php(75): CRM_Activity_Page_UserDashboard->listActivities()
#25 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/UserDashBoard.php(180): CRM_Activity_Page_UserDashboard->run()
#26 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/UserDashBoard.php(207): CRM_Contact_Page_View_UserDashBoard->buildUserDashBoard()
#27 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Contact_Page_View_UserDashBoard->run((Array:2), NULL)
#28 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#29 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#30 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(116): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#31 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#32 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(392): require_once("/home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civic...")
#33 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(372): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civic...")
#34 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(98): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#35 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(152): JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()
#36 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(252): JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()
#37 /home/coursede/public_html/accueil/administrator/index.php(47): JApplicationCms->execute()
#38 {main}

DB Error: no such field
```

any explanation ?

Regards

Comment: Do you have any custom modifications/extensions? I'm wondering if that 0LEFT thing is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You've found a bug - it looks like a typo (a missing space), which is easy enough to fix.  Unfortunately, you've left out some of the information needed to fix this.  Please edit your post with the error info that appears BELOW the words "DB Error: no such field", which will contain the full SQL statement that failed - right now we can only see a snippet, which doesn't include the broken part.